# Enum select list ID not being assigned to SQL using ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The base for my selects lists come from an enum (in the model):

```
public enum week : int
{
    Every = 0,
    First = 1,
    Second = 2,
    Third = 3,
    Fourth = 4,
    Last = 5

}

public enum weekday : int
{
    Sunday = 0,
    Monday = 1,
    Tuesday = 2,
    Wednesday = 3,
    Thursday = 4,
    Friday = 5,
    Saturday = 6,
}
```

I send these to the View using ViewBag as seen in the following function(in the controller):

```
     private void PopulateDropDown(object selectedLocation = null, )
        {
            var LocationQuery = from c in db.Location orderby c.name select c;
            ViewBag.LocationSelect = new SelectList(LocationQuery, "LocationID", "name", selectedLocation);

            var statuses = from week w in Enum.GetValues(typeof(week))
                           select new { ID = (int)w, Name= w.ToString() };
            ViewBag.week = new SelectList(statuses, "ID", "Name");
            var weekdayFormat = from weekday s in Enum.GetValues(typeof(weekday))
                           select new { ID = (int)s, Name = s.ToString() };
            ViewBag.weekday = new SelectList(weekdayFormat, "ID", "Name");
        }
```

For this example, you can ignore the LocationQuery (even though IT'S not working either...)

And in the view I have:

```
@Html.DropDownList("locationID", (SelectList)ViewBag.LocationSelect, "Select a location")
```

and

```
         @Html.DropDownList("Week", (SelectList)ViewBag.TypeSelect, "Week")
         @Html.DropDownList("weekday", (SelectList)ViewBag.TypeSelect, "Day")
```

However, none of the data I send gets collected as part of the Model:

```
public class Schedule
{

    public Schedule()
    {
        Times = new List<TimeofDay>();
    }
    public int ScheduleID { get; set; }
    public bool isDisabled { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("For Delivery")]
    public bool isDeliver { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TimeofDay> Times { get; set; }
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
    public int Week { get; set; }
    public int weekday { get; set; }
}
```

When rendered the Select list looks as I wanted:

```
         <select id="Week" name="week"><option value="">Week</option>

<option value="0">Every</option>

<option value="1">First</option>

<option value="2">Second</option>

<option value="3">Third</option>

<option value="4">Fourth</option>

<option value="5">Last</option>

</select>
```

However, I cannot get the data of the values sent to the controller on POST.  I cannot get the value of the week by doing schedule.week as expected.  Am I missing a step on posting int values collected from a selectlist, polulated by an enum, and stored as an int?

(Thanks for reading)

Andrew

Comment: If I use week Weeks or weekday weekday (using the enum as the object type in the EF defintion) the table in the database drops the columns 'Week' and 'weekday'

Comment: btw staring at the word 'week' for long periods of time will make you question if that is the correct spelling.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you set ViewBag.TypeSelect.

Have you tried using DropDownListFor?

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Week, (SelectList)ViewBag.week, "Week")
```

**EDIT**

Also, is your view definitely strongly typed? Can you show that?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your POST action takes a Schedule model as argument:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(Schedule model)
{
    ...
}
```

Now let's first take a look at the first dropdown:

```
@Html.DropDownList("locationID", (SelectList)ViewBag.LocationSelect, "Select a location")
```

When submitted it will send its value as `locationID=123` in the POST request. Now looking at the Schedule there is no property called `LocationID` on it so it is perfectly normal that you don't get its value. You have a `Location` property which presumably has a `LocationID` property. So you could modify your drop down like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Location.LocationID", (SelectList)ViewBag.LocationSelect, "Select a location")
```

Now the enum types. When I tested they both worked for me. I was able to get the proper integer values in the POST action inside the `Week` and `weekday` properties corresponding to the values selected in the dropdowns.